# How can I override the default Next JS routing behaviour to terminate a path and ignore sub-paths while delivering entire URL through useRouter?

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, url-routing

I want to access page elements using the URL address bar with Next.js to replicate some of React Routers' functionality.

Example:

I have a Next.js page called demo (in `pages` folder) that I can access with `nextjs.com/demo` using basic Next.js page routing.

`Demo.js` renders like this:

```
<div class="demo">
  <div id="link1">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="link2">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to go to straight to my `#link` anchors via the address bar.

e.g.

`nextjs.com/demo/link1` takes me to link1

not

`nextjs.com/demo#link1` (which I know works fine)

I know I could extract the `/link` section and convert it to a `#link` and use the react router to go to it but problem is Nextjs.com gives me a 404 not found because the router (correctly) thinks it's a page. How can I tell the router that the end of the URL for this routing is demo?

How do i achieve this without react router? Is there some middleware magic will allow me to do this for a specific set of routes?